# Converting SQL Query to LINQ for EntityFramework

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am having trouble translating following query to EF:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
[CompanyId]
,[CompanyNumber]
,[ReturnsLastMadeUpDate]
FROM [CHX].[dbo].[CompanyDetailsDailyDump]
WHERE [InsertDate] BETWEEN '2012-12-19' and '2013-01-20'
ORDER BY [ReturnsLastMadeUpDate] DESC
```

The main issue is with the Distinct(). How can I select above three specific columns to be compared for distinct rather than all the columns.
Regards

Comment: Did you google it? .Distinct() would appear to be the answer. Why am I doing you google searches?

Comment: Yeah, but the distinct will compare all available columns rather than only three. If only specific columns are select able, this could also solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to apply Distinct after all other operations. I.e.:

```
CompanyDetailsDaily
    .Where(x => x.InsertDate < DateTime.Parse('2013-01-20') && 
            x.InsertDate > DateTime.Parse('2012-12-19'))
    .OrderBy(x => x.ReturnsLastMadeUpDate)
    .Select(x => new{x.CompanyID,x.CompanyNumber,x.ReturnsLastMadeUpDate})
    .Distinct();
```

Be careful with the date inclusion (one of the >/< symbols may need to be replaced with =>/<=)

Comment: Thank You very much, saved the day.

Comment: You're welcome! And welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to accept and/or upvote answers to questions you've liked.